# get function of a class variable

Tags: php

connect is a class variable that is also an object that is connected to the database. How can I get the function of the variable? In Java I think it would be something like this.variable.method();

```
public function userLoginCh($username, $password, $userId, $address, $birthday)
{
    $mdPass = md5($password);
    $addRequestString = "INSERT INTO partnerRequest (userId, address, password, birthday) VALUES (:userId, :address, :mdPass, :birthday)";
    $addRequestQuery = $this->connect->prepare($addRequestString);
    $addRequestQuery->bindParam(':userId', $userId);
    $addRequestQuery->bindParam(':address', $address);
    $addRequestQuery->bindParam(':mdPass', $mdPass);
    $addRequestQuery->bindParam(':birthday', $birthday);
}
```

Comment: You already did it: `$this->connect->prepare($addRequestString);`

Comment: **Note:** md5 is not secure enough to hash passwords.

Comment: What should I use to hash a password?

Comment: "the function of the variable" what

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
$this->variable->function();
```

Ok, let's add an example:

```
class A {
    function say_hi() {
        echo 'Hi!';
    }
}

class B {
    private $class_a;

    function __construct() {
        $this->class_a = new A;
    }

    function say_what_a_says() {
        $this->class_a->say_hi();
    }
}

$b = new B;
$b->say_what_a_says(); // prints out: Hi!
```